# When using Dependance Injection, is there a difference between of calling a service by reference or directly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, factory, controllers

**QUESTION:**

Is there any difference between these two examples of using a factory service?

Example 1:

```
angular.module('ramenBattleNetworkApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Helpers) {
     var testArray = [1,2,3,4];
     // pass Helpers to var helpers
     var helpers = Helpers;
     helpers.arrayRotate(testArray, true);
  });
```

Example 2:

```
angular.module('ramenBattleNetworkApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Helpers) {
     var testArray = [1,2,3,4];
     Helpers.arrayRotate(testArray, true);
  });
```

factory:Helpers

```
angular.module('ramenBattleNetworkApp')
  .factory('Helpers', function () {     
    var Helpers = {};

    Helpers = {
      history: [],
      arrayRotate: function(arr, reverse){
        Helpers.history.push(arr);
        if(reverse)
          arr.push(arr.shift());
        else
          arr.unshift(arr.pop());
        return arr;
      }
    };
    return Helpers;
  });
});
```

**Why do I want to know?**
I've noticed in the past by calling functions inside a factory and passing them between controllers can take a big hit on performance *(example 1)* and I've never known why.

While this current example is contrived in comparison,  I have a hypothesis that the factory creates a new object every time.  If multiple controllers were `$watch()` for changes on the factory's `Helpers.history` and the factory was a larger object; maybe this is why there is a performance hit.  Lastly, perhaps by saving it into a local variable in the controller, I could control the

Or I have no idea what I'm talking about.

Comment: Factory creates a singleton. The same object will be injected into different controllers of the same app.

Comment: Is it a new instance of the object or is it literally the same object between controllers.  and what about if I go var thing = new Helpers?  what is the difference?

Comment: It is literally the same object - a singleton. I honestly don't think there is a difference between using `var helper = Helper` or just `Helper`

Comment: thanks man if you wanna answer the question I can make it correct?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's DI system injects the same instance of the service everywhere in the app. It is a singleton.

As such, there shouldn't be any difference in performance between assigning the service to a local variable:

```
var helper = Helper;
helper.doSomething();
```

And using the service directly:

```
Helper.doSomething();
```